# How to Reference a Existing Security Group in CloudFormation Template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to create a CF template to deploy a Lambda function. I want to assign it to security group named "default".

My CF template looks like this:

```
LambdaFunction:
  Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
  Properties:
    VpcConfig:
      SecurityGroupIds:
        - sg-085XXXXXXXX
```

I am able to assign this particular Security group using its ID. But I want to refer to the SG name "default" instead of SG id , as I want to deploy my Lambda in different AWS accounts. Is there any way to fetch the id of existing Security group and use it in CF template.

Comment: You will have to retrieve it externally and then pass it in as parameter. Either a wrapper around CF call (ugly) or use CDK.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot reference security groups by name. You could write a custom resource that looks up the resource name and outputs the Id.

An example of the *reverse* setup can be found here:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/four-ways-to-retrieve-any-aws-service-property-using-aws-cloudformation-part-1/

It actually created a custom resource for which the input is a security group id and the output is a security group name.

The template:

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Parameters: 
  vpcID: 
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPC::Id
    Description: Enter VPC Id

Resources:
  CfnEC2SecurityGroup: 
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup' 
    Properties: 
      GroupDescription: CFN2 Security Group Description
      VpcId: !Ref vpcID

  LambdaBasicExecutionRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            Service: lambda.amazonaws.com
          Action: sts:AssumeRole
      Path: /
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: CustomLambdaEC2DescribePolicy
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: '2012-10-17'
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - logs:CreateLogGroup
                  - logs:CreateLogStream
                  - logs:PutLogEvents
                Resource: arn:aws:logs:*:*:*
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - ec2:DescribeSecurityGroups
                Resource: '*'

  CustomSGResource:
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::CustomResource
    Properties:
      ServiceToken: !GetAtt 'CustomFunction.Arn'
      ResourceRef: !Ref 'CfnEC2SecurityGroup'

  CustomFunction:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: index.lambda_handler
      Description: "Retrieves EC2 Security group name"
      Timeout: 30
      Role: !GetAtt 'LambdaBasicExecutionRole.Arn'
      Runtime: python3.7
      Code:
        ZipFile: |
          import json
          import logging
          import cfnresponse
          import boto3
          
          logger = logging.getLogger()
          logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

          def lambda_handler(event, context):
            logger.info('got event {}'.format(event))  
            try: 
              responseData = {}
              if event['RequestType'] == 'Delete':
                logger.info('Incoming RequestType: Delete operation') 
                cfnresponse.send(event, context, cfnresponse.SUCCESS, {})
              if event['RequestType'] in ["Create", "Update"]:                      
                # 1. retrieve resource reference ID or Name
                ResourceRef=event['ResourceProperties']['ResourceRef']
                # 2. retrieve boto3 client    
                client = boto3.client('ec2')
                # 3. Invoke describe/retrieve function using ResourceRef
                response = client.describe_security_groups(GroupIds=[ResourceRef])
                # 4. Parse and return required attributes 
                responseData = {}
                responseData['SecurityGroup-Name']= response.get('SecurityGroups')[0].get('GroupName')
                logger.info('Retrieved SecurityGroup-Name!')
                cfnresponse.send(event, context, cfnresponse.SUCCESS, responseData)
              else:
                logger.info('Unexpected RequestType!') 
                cfnresponse.send(event, context, cfnresponse.SUCCESS, responseData)
            except Exception as err:
              logger.error(err)
              responseData = {"Data": str(err)}
              cfnresponse.send(event,context,cfnresponse.FAILED,responseData)
            return              
Outputs:
  SecurityGroupID:
    Description: Security Group ID
    Value: !Ref CfnEC2SecurityGroup
  SecurityGroupName:
    Description: Security Group Name from the custom resource
    Value: !GetAtt 'CustomSGResource.SecurityGroup-Name'
```

The blogpost explains the template step by step.

You'd need to reverse the logic of the lambda so it looks up the security group by name and then returns the Id.